# Any permanent solution for this PKIX Android Studio Issue , while accessing Behind the proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, pkix

On a new Project on Android Studio 4.2.2 I get this :

```
 Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

dl.gogle.com has the same domain as google.com which is already added in the certificates from the Android Studio.